# How to Screen Capture in High Quality Independent of Monitor Resolution

Tags: windows, google-chrome, video, graphics-card, resolution

This is a question that has been nagging at me for some time. Let's say I want to write some software that live streams a video game in real time in ultra-high quality. Say I rent a machine from a cloud provider with the latest and greatest hardware, BUT has no monitor with it. At best, I can get a 600x400 view of the desktop through some remote desktop setup.

How can I go about capturing the video of the running game at the quality I want?

Some additional context: I've been so curious about this that I set up the above scenario to the T. I have a server running powerful hardware. I jump into a Google Meets call and attempt to share the screen on the powerful machine. Much to my surprise, the shared video seems to be rendered at the resolution of the display--poor quality. Considering that my hardware is capable of recording even as high as 4k, and the running game is obviously capable of better graphics, there must be a way to force the screen capture to fetch a higher quality.

Any insight on this issue is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If it were *downloading* a file, e.g., from YouTube, resolution could be specified, but if capturing the *screen buffer*, not. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for that helpful link! So would it be safe to say that screen sharing works something like this: CPU fetches available display and sets screen buffer to that size. Screen capture software reads the content stored in that screen buffer, encodes it, and transports to the peer that is viewing the screen sharing.

Does that seem accurate?

Comment: AFAIK, yes... though I claim no expertise here.